# Deseo hacer una consulta en la base de datos y tengo el siguiente error '[' expected, got 'group'

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Al usar el having en una consulta se genera el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la parte del error, estas poniendo un segundo group by. Deberia haber uno solo.

Comment: Además, he revisado tu pregunta y tengo algunas recomendaciones que hacer. 1 - Lee [Un Fragmento de Código vale más que mil Imagenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880) para que entiendas por que tu pregunta podría no ser bien recibida y terminar cerrada y/o con votos negativos.